# Java String - See if a string contains only numbers and not letters

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I have a string that I load throughout my application, and it changes from numbers to letters and such. I have a simple `if` statement to see if it contains letters or numbers but, something isn't quite working correctly. Here is a snippet.

```
String text = "abc"; 
String number; 

if (text.contains("[a-zA-Z]+") == false && text.length() > 2) {
    number = text; 
}
```

Although the `text` variable does contain letters, the condition returns as `true`. The and `&&` should eval as both conditions having to be `true` in order to process the `number = text;`

==============================

***Solution:***

I was able to solve this by using this following code provided by a comment on this question. All other post are valid as well!

What I used that worked came from the first comment. Although all the example code provided seems to be valid as well!

```
String text = "abc"; 
String number; 

if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", text) == false && text.length() > 2) {
    number = text; 
}
```

Comment: contains does not take a regexp as input. Use either `matches("\\d{2,}")` or try with a `Pattern` and `Matcher`

Comment: Can the string have a decimal value or only integer values?

Comment: Why are you checking text.length() > 2? What's the reason?

Comment: @RedHatcc `Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", text) == false` can be simplified to `!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", text)`

Comment: Using java streaming API `boolean isNumeric = someString.chars().allMatch(x -> Character.isDigit(x));` form [`Max Malysh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35150400/5081877) Post.

Comment: This negative regex seems simplest to me: `! oddStr.matches("\\D+")`

Answer (score 430, accepted):

If you'll be processing the number as text, then change:

```
if (text.contains("[a-zA-Z]+") == false && text.length() > 2){
```

to:

```
if (text.matches("[0-9]+") && text.length() > 2) {
```

Instead of checking that the string *doesn't* contain alphabetic characters, check to be sure it contains *only* numerics.

If you actually want to use the numeric value, use `Integer.parseInt()` or `Double.parseDouble()` as others have explained below.

---

As a side note, it's generally considered bad practice to compare boolean values to `true` or `false`.  Just use `if (condition)` or `if (!condition)`.

Comment: You probably want to add anchors (e.g. `^[0-9]+$`) otherwise `abc123def` will be considered a number.

Comment: I don't think that's required. `matches()` returns true if and only if it's a complete match from beginning to end.

Comment: "^-?\d+\.?\d*$" will compare the whole string and only match if it is a valid number (negatives and decimals included). For example, it will match 1, 10, 1.0, -1, -1.0, etc. It'll also match on "1." but that can often be parsed anyway.

Comment: There is no need to call `&& (text.length() > 2)`. Everything can be checked in regex pattern: `if (text.matches("[0-9]{3,}")`

Comment: What about commas or dots for numbers that are not integers?

Comment: The method is called `match()`.

Comment: what if you had float or a double?

Comment: What is the purpose of checking the length of the text?

Answer (score 26):

In order to simply check whether the string only contains ALPHABETS use the following code:

```
if (text.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
   // your operations
}
```

In order to simply check whether the string only contains NUMBER use the following code:

```
if (text.matches("[0-9]+")){
   // your operations
}
```

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 22):

This is how I would do it:

```
if(text.matches("^[0-9]*$") && text.length() > 2){
    //...
}
```

The `$` will avoid a partial match e.g; `1B`.

Comment: I don't need the `text.length() > 2` part, so I just replaced `^[0-9]*$` by `^[0-9]+$` to be sure I have at least one number.

Comment: `text.matches("^[0-9]*$")` is the same as `text.matches("[0-9]*")`.

Answer (score 20):

You can also use [NumberUtil.isCreatable(String str)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.7/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-) from Apache Commons

Comment: I don't think `NumberUtil.isCreatable(String str)` is correct to use for what the original question asks for. E.g., `NumberUtil.isCreatable( "09" )` returns `false`, even though `"09"` *contains only numbers*.

Comment: even NumberUtils.isCreatable("068907") will return false

Answer (score 14):

Performance-wise `parseInt` and such are much worser than other solutions, because at least require exception handling.

I've run jmh tests and have found that iterating over String using `charAt` and comparing chars with boundary chars is the fastest way to test if string contains only digits.

## JMH testing

Tests compare performance of `Character.isDigit` vs `Pattern.matcher().matches` vs `Long.parseLong` vs checking char values.

These ways can produce different result for non-ascii strings and strings containing +/- signs.

Tests run in Throughput mode (**greater is better**) with 5 warmup iterations and 5 test iterations.

### Results

Note that `parseLong` is almost 100 times slower than `isDigit` for first test load.

```
## Test load with 25% valid strings (75% strings contain non-digit symbols)

Benchmark       Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
testIsDigit    thrpt    5  9.275 ± 2.348  ops/s
testPattern    thrpt    5  2.135 ± 0.697  ops/s
testParseLong  thrpt    5  0.166 ± 0.021  ops/s

## Test load with 50% valid strings (50% strings contain non-digit symbols)

Benchmark              Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
testCharBetween       thrpt    5  16.773 ± 0.401  ops/s
testCharAtIsDigit     thrpt    5  8.917 ± 0.767  ops/s
testCharArrayIsDigit  thrpt    5  6.553 ± 0.425  ops/s
testPattern           thrpt    5  1.287 ± 0.057  ops/s
testIntStreamCodes    thrpt    5  0.966 ± 0.051  ops/s
testParseLong         thrpt    5  0.174 ± 0.013  ops/s
testParseInt          thrpt    5  0.078 ± 0.001  ops/s
```

### Test suite

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class StringIsNumberBenchmark {
    private static final long CYCLES = 1_000_000L;
    private static final String[] STRINGS = {"12345678901","98765432177","58745896328","35741596328", "123456789a1", "1a345678901", "1234567890 "};
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

    @Benchmark
    public void testPattern() {
        for (int i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++) {
            for (String s : STRINGS) {
                boolean b = false;
                b = PATTERN.matcher(s).matches();
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testParseLong() {
        for (int i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++) {
            for (String s : STRINGS) {
                boolean b = false;
                try {
                    Long.parseLong(s);
                    b = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // no-op
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testCharArrayIsDigit() {
        for (int i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++) {
            for (String s : STRINGS) {
                boolean b = false;
                for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
                    b = Character.isDigit(c);
                    if (!b) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testCharAtIsDigit() {
        for (int i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++) {
            for (String s : STRINGS) {
                boolean b = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                    b = Character.isDigit(s.charAt(j));
                    if (!b) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testIntStreamCodes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++) {
            for (String s : STRINGS) {
                boolean b = false;
                b = s.chars().allMatch(c -> c > 47 && c < 58);
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testCharBetween() {
        for (int i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++) {
            for (String s : STRINGS) {
                boolean b = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                    char charr = s.charAt(j);
                    b = '0' <= charr && charr <= '9';
                    if (!b) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Updated on Feb 23, 2018

- Add two more cases - one using `charAt` instead of creating extra array and another using `IntStream` of char codes
- Add immediate break if non-digit found for looped test cases
- Return false for empty string for looped test cases

## Updated on Feb 23, 2018

- Add one more test case (the fastest!) that compares char value without using stream

Comment: If you look at the code of toCharArray, it is allocating a char array and copying the chars (i think that could be expensive). What about if you just iterate the string using an index and charAt, would it be faster? 

Would be interesting also if you could add the solution from Andy to your tests: boolean isNum = text.chars().allMatch(c -> c >= 48 && c <= 57)

Answer (score 9):

*Apache Commons Lang* provides [`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNumeric(CharSequence cs)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.7/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-), which takes as an argument a `String` and checks if it consists of purely numeric characters (including numbers from non-Latin scripts). That method returns `false` if there are characters such as space, minus, plus, and decimal separators such as comma and dot.

Other methods of that class allow for further numeric checks.

Answer (score 9):

A solution with Java 8 streams and lambda

```
String data = "12345";
boolean isOnlyNumbers = data.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
```

Answer (score 6):

```java
StringUtils.isNumeric("1234")
```

this works fine.

Comment: If you use Apache's StringUtils you should be carefully as this function accepts more than the characters 0-9: For example "१२३". See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score 4):

boolean isNum = text.chars().allMatch(c -> c >= 48 && c <= 57)

Comment: to reduce magic numbers, you could compare as follows: ``boolean isNum = text.chars().allMatch(c -> c >= '0' && c <= '9')``

Answer (score 4):

Below regexs can be used to check if a string has only number or not:

`if (str.matches(".*[^0-9].*"))  or if (str.matches(".*\\D.*"))`

Both conditions above will return `true` if String containts non-numbers. On `false`, string has only numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regex.Match

```
if(text.matches("\\d*")&& text.length() > 2){
    System.out.println("number");
}
```

Or you could use onversions like `Integer.parseInt(String)` or better `Long.parseLong(String)` for bigger numbers
like for example:

```
private boolean onlyContainsNumbers(String text) {
    try {
        Long.parseLong(text);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then test with:

```
if (onlyContainsNumbers(text) && text.length() > 2) {
    // do Stuff
}
```

Comment: .matches("^\\d+$")

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but I consider it still relevant today.

Although the String matching solution is the most elegant one (at least in my opinion), it is far from being performant. So, if you plan to use this method at scale, you might consider alternative implementations.

I wrote a few short classes for comparing the run times of various implementations. For each implementation, I ran 100 million iterations, half with an all-numeric input (so the method returns `true`) and half with letters (so the method returns `false`) and following are the results of the runs on my machine.

## Alternatives

### String matching solution

`text.matches("\\d*");`

Total runtime: 19206 ms

### Pattern matching solution

Similar to the String matching solution, but with better running time because pattern compilation is done only once:

`PATTERN.matcher(text).matches();`

where PATTERN is defined only once as such: `final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d*");`

Total runtime: 9193 ms

### IntStream solution

Less concise than the matching solutions, but faster:

`text.isEmpty() || IntStream.range(0, text.length()).allMatch(i -> Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i)));`

Total runtime: 5568 ms

### Simple loop solution

Using the same concept as the IntStream solution, but more verbose:

```
boolean allDigits = true;
if (!text.isEmpty()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i))) {
            allDigits = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return allDigits;
```

Total runtime: 235 ms

### Commons lang solution

There is also the commons lang solution which doesn't require you to write any code, but to depend on an external library instead:

`StringUtils.isNumeric(text);`

Total runtime: 1433 ms

## Conclusion

What this test shows is that - leaving aside the external dependency solution - the more elegant the code, the less performant it is, with the most "primitive" solution being also the fastest running one.

That being said, I'm an advocate of clean code, so if you only need to call this method a few times, definitely go for one of the more elegant solutions; in many cases code quality is more important than performance. However, if you know you will be calling it a lot or if it's going to be part of a library, consider going for one of the less elegant but more performant solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of facilities to obtain numbers from `String`s in Java (and vice versa). You may want to skip the regex part to spare yourself the complication of that.

For example, you could try and see what [`Double.parseDouble(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) returns for you. It should throw a `NumberFormatException` if it does not find an appropriate value in the string. I would suggest this technique because you could actually make use of the value represented by the `String` as a numeric type.

Comment: Using an exception as a why to test your input might be a bad idea, exceptions create a big overhead.

Comment: @OfirLuzon I agree that exceptions are not a great way to handle expected cases that are going to arise. However I think it's hard to tell if there would be a performance hit without more context.

Answer (score 2):

This code is already written. If you don't mind the (extremely) minor performance hit--which is probably no worse than doing a regex match--use [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) or [Double.parseDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29). That'll tell you right away if a String is only numbers (or *is a* number, as appropriate). If you need to handle longer strings of numbers, both [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) and [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) sport constructors that accept Strings. Any of these will throw a [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if you try to pass it a non-number (integral or decimal, based on the one you choose, of course). Alternately, depending on your requirements, just iterate the characters in the String and check [Character.isDigit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) and/or [Character.isLetter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;

class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] argh) {
        boolean ans = CheckNumbers("123");
        if (ans == true) {
            System.out.println("String contains numbers only");
        } else {
            System.out.println("String contains other values as well");

        }
    }


    public static boolean CheckNumbers(String input) {
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < input.length(); ctr++) {
            if ("1234567890".contains(Character.valueOf(input.charAt(ctr)).toString())) {
                continue;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is my code, hope this will help you !**

```
 public boolean isDigitOnly(String text){

    boolean isDigit = false;

    if (text.matches("[0-9]+") && text.length() > 2) {
        isDigit = true;
    }else {
        isDigit = false;
    }

    return isDigit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Character first_letter_or_number = query.charAt(0);
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (Character.isDigit())
                {

                }
                else if (Character.isLetter())
                {

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Working test example

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class PaserNo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String text = "gg";

        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(text)) {
            if (stringContainsNumber(text)) {
                int no=Integer.parseInt(text.trim());
                System.out.println("inside"+no);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Outside");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static boolean stringContainsNumber(String s) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        return m.find();
    }
}
```

Still your code can be break by "1a" etc so you need to check exception

```
if (!StringUtils.isBlank(studentNbr)) {
                try{
                    if (isStringContainsNumber(studentNbr)){
                    _account.setStudentNbr(Integer.parseInt(studentNbr.trim()));
                }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    logger.info("Exception during parse studentNbr"+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Method for checking no is string or not

```
private boolean isStringContainsNumber(String s) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        return m.find();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice to involve any exception throwing/handling into such a typical scenario.


Therefore a parseInt() is not nice, but a regex is an elegant solution for this, but take care of the following:
-fractions
-negative numbers
-decimal separator might differ in contries (e.g. ',' or '.')
-sometimes it is allowed to have a so called thousand separator, like a space or a comma e.g. 12,324,1000.355

To handle all the necessary cases in your application you have to be careful, but this regex covers the typical scenarios (positive/negative and fractional, separated by a dot): ^[-+]?\d*.?\d+$

For testing, I recommend [regexr.com](http://regexr.com).

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified version of Adam Bodrogi's:

```
public class NumericStr {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Matches: "+NumericStr.isNumeric("20"));         // Should be true
    System.out.println("Matches: "+NumericStr.isNumeric("20,00"));          // Should be true
    System.out.println("Matches: "+NumericStr.isNumeric("30.01"));          // Should be true
    System.out.println("Matches: "+NumericStr.isNumeric("30,000.01"));          // Should be true
    System.out.println("Matches: "+NumericStr.isNumeric("-2980"));          // Should be true
    System.out.println("Matches: "+NumericStr.isNumeric("$20"));            // Should be true
    System.out.println("Matches: "+NumericStr.isNumeric("jdl"));            // Should be false
    System.out.println("Matches: "+NumericStr.isNumeric("2lk0"));           // Should be false
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String stringVal) {
    if (stringVal.matches("^[\\$]?[-+]?[\\d\\.,]*[\\.,]?\\d+$")) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Had to use this today so just posted my modifications. Includes currency, thousands comma or period notation, and some validations. Does not include other currency notations (euro, cent), verification commas are every third digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test{  
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    boolean status=false;
    System.out.println("Enter the String : ");
    str = sc.nextLine();
    
    char ch[] = str.toCharArray();
    
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {
        if(ch[i]=='1'||ch[i]=='2'||ch[i]=='3'||ch[i]=='4'||ch[i]=='5'||ch[i]=='6'||ch[i]=='7'||ch[i]=='8'||ch[i]=='9'||ch[i]=='0') {
            ch[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {
        if(ch[i] != 0) {
            System.out.println("Mixture of letters and Digits");
            status = false;
            break;
        }
        else
            status = true;
    }
    
    if(status == true){
        System.out.println("Only Digits are present");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample. Find only the digits in a String and Process formation as needed.

```
text.replaceAll("\\d(?!$)", "$0 ");
```

For more info check google Docs
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern Where you can use **Pattern**

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean flag = false;
        System.out.print("Enter String : ");
        String str = new Scanner(System.in).next();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (str.length() <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("String length Can't be zero.");
                return;
            }
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            int c = ch;
            if (c >= 48 && c <= 58)
            {
                flag = true;
            } else
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            System.out.println("input [" + str + "] contains number only.");
        } else
            System.out.println("input [" + str + "] have some non string values in it.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[a-zA-Z]{2,}` as well.

where `[a-zA-Z]` checks for alphabets only and `{2,}` checks the length, should be greater than 2

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in my code, and here is a simple function to check if the string value can be converted into an int.

```java
    private boolean isOnlyNumber(String zipCode) {
        for (int i = 0; i < zipCode.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(zipCode.charAt(i)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

hope this helps.