# SQL #1064 while using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

So I wrote up some SQL statements and as I went to test them I was greeted with the following error. Why is it rejecting this?

```
CREATE TABLE Student 
(stud_id INT unsigned NOT NULL, 
stud_name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
stud_phone INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
stud_date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
stud_city VARCHAR NOT NULL,
stud_address VARCHAR NOT NULL,
stud_postcode INT(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (stud_id, stud_phone)
);
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, 
>      stud_phone INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
>      stud_date_of_birth DATE NOT ' at line 3

Comment: You need to add a length to the each of the  `VARCHAR` column definitions, like `VARCHAR(256)`.

Comment: INT may not be the best choice for a telephone number. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353778/which-is-best-data-type-for-phone-number-in-mysql-and-what-should-java-type-mapp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the length to the `VARCHAR` datatype like `VARCHAR(100)`.
This is the only thing with your query.

Your modified query looks like as below.

```
CREATE TABLE Student 
(stud_id INT unsigned NOT NULL, 
stud_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
stud_phone INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
stud_date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
stud_city VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
stud_address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
stud_postcode INT(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (stud_id, stud_phone)
);
```

After correction this if the error still showing in you phpMyadmin then you have to remove `Delimiter` from the Delimiter textbox in your phpmyadmin place at the bottom of you query filed.

[image]

Comment: Is this query executed successfully?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for clarifying that for me