# Access violation 1064 when using NULL in sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a error in my SQL statement. I am using NULL in my command and I guess thats the problem, but I am not sure. So what am I doing wrong here ?

Code:

```
function run()
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE %%EVENT%% SET lock = NULL WHERE 'lock' IS NOT NULL";

        Database::get()->update($sql);
    }
```

Error:

```
USER ERROR: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'lock = NULL WHERE 'lock' IS NOT NULL' at line 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL #1064 while using phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354586/sql-1064-while-using-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Which kind of SQL are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: `lock` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You should either use ticks around it, or find a different name for your column. `SET \`lock\` = NULL WHERE \`lock\` IS NOT NULL";`

Comment: Thanks the ticks worked for me. I tested them before and it did not work, but now suddently everything works as it should. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the apostrophes around the second 'lock':

`UPDATE %%EVENT%% SET lock = NULL WHERE lock IS NOT NULL`

Without knowing the SQL dialect you're using it's hard to further diagnose the issue. It's possible that `lock` is a reserved keyword. What are you trying to achieve with `%%EVENT%%`? I assume you're trying to use wildcard.