# Does the maximum length of INT need to be specified in MySQL when creating a column?

Tags: mysql, int

I am writing an SQL query for creating a new column in a table. Part of my query includes this:

```
`phone` INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

The phone must have exactly 8 digits because that is how phone number works for the countries that I am working with. But I am not sure if I need to use `INT(8)` or only `INT`. The other way to write that portion would be:

```
`phone` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

I know for `VARCHAR` for example, you specify the length. For example: `VARCHAR(50)`. But in the case of `INT` I am not sure, since in MySQL, it is already known that `INT` can store a maximum value of 4294967295 when it is unsigned, so using `INT(8)` may not make sense because `INT` will always be `INT` and by definition, able to store a maximum value of 4294967295 when using `UNSIGNED` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html). Thank you.

Comment: It's fantastically unlikely that something called 'phone' would be an integer. You rarely need to add up phone numbers, and 01234 and 1234 are NOT the same phone number!

Comment: `+44 303 123 7300` is a phone number, as is `(555)555-5555x2202` and so is `1-800-ODD-BIRD`. They are not just "numbers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INT(8) is an obsolete formatting construct. Its best to ignore those on int types.

`VARCHAR` is probably better for PHONE types that don't have numberic operations done on them.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I found the same advice at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353778/which-is-best-data-type-for-phone-number-in-mysql-and-what-should-java-type-mapp.