# Android Edittext Validate for all digits

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

Hi in my android application I have an edittext where inputtype is person name, but for that special characters are allowed, what I need is an edittext where I need to enter only digits and letters. But I need to validate for all digits, if all digits enter means error message need to shown.

I did like this

```
android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM"

            android:inputType="textFilter"
```

and with this we can enter all digits also... but if user enter all digits I need to show a error message.

Comment: Use regular expression to achieve this.

Comment: Please take a look at following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15111450/2793134

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15111463/2793134

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an in-built function in `TextUtils` class to check if the string contains only digits. You could use that.

```
if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(your_string)) {
//show error message
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to check is the string is Alphanumeric or not.
So you can actually use [Apache Commons Lang's StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

```
StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(editText.getText().toString())
```

Comment: so this checks whether it is alpha numeric .. but name can be only letters .. for most of the people name is only letters.. then how we will check

Comment: Wait so you only want the user to enter letters only without digit?

Comment: For a name most of the time only letters will be there or combination of letters and numbers, numbers alone wont be there.. I need to validate the numbers alone part

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for all digits like

```
 public static boolean validateString(String input)
    {
        try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
            return false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return true;
        }
    }
```