# How to find whether string contains every digit or not through regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

Want to find whether my string contains every digit from 0 to 9 or not. I am currently using following logic :

```
if (str.contains("0") && str.contains("1") && str.contains("2") && str.contains("3") && str.contains("4") && str.contains("5") && str.contains("6") && str.contains("7") && str.contains("8") && str.contains("9"))
{
    return true;
}
```

I believe this will not be very optimized if string is too big. How can I use a pattern and find using String.matches whether it has all numbers or not through regex ?

This is not a duplicate of most other regex questions in the forum wherein 'OR' related char patterns are discussed, here we're talking about 'AND'. I need whether a string contains each of the given characters (i.e. digits) or not. Hope it clarifies.

Thanks,
Rajiv

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the linked one. Here, the poster asks if a string contains every digit.

Comment: Probably, but not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111420/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-only-digits-in-java

Comment: Don't think it's duplicate of said one.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, sry I didn't get that. I don't seem to see any api called chars() or filter() in String class. Was there a typo ?

Comment: @Rajiv: See [the demo](https://ideone.com/ezx73X) in Java 8.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thanks

Comment: I reopened and posted an answer.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can do this with a regular expression. Astonished, actually. Regular expressions are a subset of context-free languages are a subset of context-sensitive languages, and what you have described is essenitally a context-sensitive problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend a regex for this task as it won't look elegant. It will look like (hover mouse over to see the spoiler):

> [`str.matches("(?s)(?=[^1]*1)(?=[^2]*2)(?=[^3]*3)(?=[^4]*4)(?=[^5]*5)(?=[^6]*6)(?=[^7]*7)(?=[^8]*8)(?=[^9]*9)(?=[^0]*0).*")`](https://regex101.com/r/vT4sXp/1)

Instead, in Java 8, you can use

```
bool result = s.chars().filter(i -> i >= '0' && i <= '9').distinct().count() == 10;
```

It filters all the string characters (`s.chars()`) that are digits (`.filter(i -> i >= '0' && i <= '9')`), only keeps unique occurrences (with `.distinct()`),  and then checks their count with `.count()`. If the count is equal to 10, there are all ten ASCII digits.

So, the following code:

```
String s = "1-234-56s78===90";
System.out.println(s.chars().filter(i -> i >= '0' && i <= '9').distinct().count() == 10);
```

[prints *true*](https://ideone.com/ezx73X).