# Problematic decimalFormat.parse() in Java

Tags: java

There is a requirement that if user enters a number, parse it and `doSomething()`.
If user enters a mixture of number and string, then `doSomethingElse()`

So, I wrote the code as under:

```
String userInput = getWhatUserEntered();
try {
   DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)     
   NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(<LocaleHere>);
   Number number = decimalFormat.parse(userInput);
   doSomething(number);    // If I reach here, I will doSomething

   return;
}
catch(Exception e)  {
  // Oh.. user has entered mixture of alpha and number
}

doSomethingElse(userInput);  // If I reach here, I will doSomethingElse
return;
```

The function `getWhatUserEntered()` looks as under

```
String getWhatUserEntered()
{
  return "1923";
  //return "Oh God 1923";
  //return "1923 Oh God";
}
```

But, there is a problem.

- When user enters **1923** --> `doSomething()` is hit
- When user enters **Oh God 1923** --> `doSomethingElse()` is hit
- When user enters **1923 Oh God** --> `doSomething()` is hit. This is **wrong**
  Here I need that `doSomethingElse()` should be hit.

Is there any inbuilt (better) function to the thing I want to achieve ?
Can my code be modified to suit needs ?

Comment: The problem is probably in `getWhatUserEntered()`. It should return a full line and not a single token. If you are using Scanner.next, change it to nextLine.

Comment: indeed show what is `getWhatUserEntered();`

Comment: At present `getWhatUserEntered()` is hard-coded with values I gave in the code snippet. So no problem there

Comment: @UmNyobe It is returning harcoded values as String. The values are same as I pasted in the code snippet

Comment: @UmNyobe Edited. Check now

Comment: Maybe OT but using try-catch to implement logic is not a good style. This could be a better way to check for numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575624/java-string-see-if-a-string-contains-only-numbers-and-not-letters

Comment: @Eran Check now. I edited the code

Comment: Why don't you use `String.matches()` and pass a regex to it?

Comment: You could also just do `Integer.parseInt` and catch this exception if you are just out for one single number

Comment: Never use empty catch blocks

Comment: @SimpleGuy Just a friendly advice, trust me :)

Comment: @HRgiger, Yeah, I agree with you that one should not use try catch for logic implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is OK due to specific DecimalFormat implementation. JavaDoc says:

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a
>   number. The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

So you have to fix your code to something like this:

```
  String userInput = getWhatUserEntered();
    try {
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
        Number number = formatter.parse(userInput, position);
        if (position.getIndex() != userInput.length())
            throw new ParseException("failed to parse entire string: " + userInput, position.getIndex());
        doSomething(number);    // If I reach here, I will doSomething

        return;
    }
    catch(Exception e)  {
        // Oh.. user has entered mixture of alpha and number
    }

    doSomethingElse(userInput);  // If I reach here, I will doSomethingElse
    return;
```

Answer (score 3):

You better use some regex e.g. `userInput.matches("[0-9]+")` for matching numbers only

Comment: The question says any number can be entered. This regex doesn't check for `+`, `-`, `e`, `.`, etc.

Comment: What if the number contains a decimal marker  or thousands separator?

Comment: well that can be fixed... But regex is an solution to the problem, isn't it?

However, "-?\d*\.?\d+e[+-]?\d+" may solve the problem for scientific notation

Comment: No. What if the number is entered with a `Locale` you're not even aware of? The question specifying `<LocaleHere>` even hints that you should not use regexes.

Comment: indeed, there might be cases where regexs are not feasible

Answer (score 2):

`DecimalFormat` accepts any string if it starts with a number.

What you can do is perform an additional check.

```
try {
  DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)     
  NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(<LocaleHere>);
  Number number = decimalFormat.parse(userInput);
  if (number.toString().equals(userInput)) {
    doSomething(number);    // If I reach here, I will doSomething   
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I asked, is there is way for me to achieve the thing in need, using some inbuilt function ?

Comment: I initially wrote the very basics of the answer. Now, I edited it to add a bit more.

Comment: Thanks. Since @usual developer gives more information in answer and has answered before you, so I would accept his as an answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: Indeed, his answer is better than mine.