# Checking if a string contains only digits and then setting it only if it doesn't contain characters other than digits

Tags: java, for-loop

```
/**
 * Set the person's mobile phone number
 */
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mobile.length(); i++) {
if (!Character.isDigit(mobile.charAt(i))) {}
}
this.mobile = mobile;
}
```

So I basically need to make sure the string only contains digits, and if it contains non-digits for the method just to do nothing.
The problem I have is that if there is a random character in a string of numbers i.e. "034343a45645" it will still set the method.
Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575624/java-string-see-if-a-string-contains-only-numbers-and-not-letters

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`String.matches(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
boolean onlyDigits = mobile.matches("[0-9]+");
```

With a for loop you can just break when a non-digits is found.

```
boolean onlyDigits = true;
for (int i = 0; i < mobile.length(); i++) {
    if (!Character.isDigit(mobile.charAt(i))) {
        onlyDigits = false;
        break;
   }
}
```

Instead of breaking out of the loop, you could also just return. As it sounds like you don't want anything else to happen after. Thus eliminating the need for the `onlyDigits` variable to begin with.

Note that if `mobile.length() == 0` then `onlyDigits` would still be `true` in relation to the above for loop. So assuming `onlyDigits` should be `false` if `mobile` is an empty string, then you could initialize it as such:

```
boolean onlyDigits = !mobile.isEmpty()
```

After checking you can then assign it if `onlyDigits` is `true`.

```
if (onlyDigits)
    this.mobile = mobile;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

First: you didn't exit the loop if the if condition is false

Second: why using loop try implement tryParse like this

```
boolean tryParseInt(String value) {  
     try {  
         Integer.parseInt(value);  
         return true;  
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
         return false;  
      }  
}

if(tryParseInt(mobile)){
  this.mobile = mobile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `boolean letterFound;`

then at your for loop

whenever a letter is found use your `else` statement to set `letterFound` to `true`

then immediately stop the loop `i=mobile.length()` at your `else` statement